# How to execute or test laravel $schedule->call function via artisan

Tags: php, laravel

If we used **Laravel** scheduler with command like bellow and;

`$schedule->command('invoice:generate')`

We can execute/run it using terminal by typing this,

> `php artisan invoice:generate`

**But how we execute/run bellow mentioned `$schedule->call` types of  methods via terminal or any other way to check this?**

`$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\DeactiveELV@shutdown')->everyMinute();`

My goal is, verify Kernel.php will run `schedule()` method correctly with above mentioned `call` function.

Source code [Kernel.php]:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        \Log::info('Just for testing...');
         $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\DeactiveELV@shutdown')->everyMinute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First to Test if cron is running in your server or localhost type:
**sudo service cron status**

If not installed then install the cron:
**sudo apt-get install cron**

To enable laravel’s scheduler run below command to write cron file.
**crontab -e**

And you can select an editor if not vim opens directly. Be sure to enter there this line at the bottom:
* * * * * php /path_from_root_to_laravel_proj_folder/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1

To test if you have setup inside laravel the scheduler right, run this from your projects folder:
**php artisan schedule:run**

To run particular schedule command in console

**php /path_of_your_project/artisan command:commandname**